# Is there a specific method/Approach to improve UX/UI?

Tags: design, web

In my master thesis i aimed at improving an exisitng system UI. the solution i proposed is analysis and evaluate the system based on the documentation and running web site and next develop scenarios that address shortcommings. the scenarios help to derive use cases and task flow and navigation to come up with wireframes.
note that it doesn't neccesary for me to develop data model.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. From the HELP information on this site: [Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Can you narrow this down a bit? We're here to solve specific UX issues, but it sounds like you need something much broader here.

Comment: it seems broad but it will lead the whole design process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Official" UCD is described in ISO 9241-210:2010 http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=52075

I've never heard of anyone actually using it, but if you are looking for formal UX Design methods then that's probably the place to start.